# How to transform a list of lists in Python into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, graph

I have in Python an structure like this one

```
example = {
    ['g': 'h'],
    [
        {'a':'b'}, {'c': 'd'},
        {'a':'b'}, {'e', 'f'}
     ]
}
```

I want to create a dictionary that represents the information of this list considering it a graph in the sense that the info goes from left to right

The output I want, for the example above is:

```
output = {
{'a': 
    {'b': 
            {'c': 'd'},
            {'e', 'f'}
     }
     ,
    {'g': 'h'}
}
```

Comment: Your output is not a valid Python object. Also what output should something like `['Q']` produce if it succeeded by nothing else?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the pattern it should follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used a set of functions like

```py
def kvCombine(obj:list):
    if isinstance(obj, dict): obj = list(obj.items()) 
    if not isinstance(obj, list): return obj
    obj = [t for lt in [
        list(o.items()) if isinstance(o,dict) else [o] for o in obj
    ] for t in lt]
    
    if not all(isinstance(t, tuple) and len(t)==2 for t in obj): return obj
    kList = set(k for k, v in obj)
    kvPairs = [(ki, [v for k, v in obj if k==ki]) for ki in kList]
    return {k: v[0] if len(v)==1 else kvCombine(v) for k, v in kvPairs}

def dict_graph(pList):
    if not isinstance(pList, list): return pList
    if not pList: return None # {} # []
    if len(pList)==1: return dict_graph(pList[0])

    if any(isinstance(p, list) for p in pList):
        return kvCombine([  (p,None) if not isinstance(p,list) else 
                            (p[0],dict_graph(p[1:])) for p in pList if p!=[] ])
    
    if len(pList)==2: return {pList[0]: pList[1]}
    return {pList[0]: dict_graph(pList[1:])}
```

then with a list of lists:

```py
example = [[ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [ 'a', 'b', 'e', 'f'], [ 'g', 'h']]
example_graph = dict_graph(example)
```

`example_graph` would look like

> ```py
> {'a': {'b': {'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}}, 'g': 'h'}
> ```

> ```json
> {
>     "a": {
>         "b": {
>             "c": "d",
>             "e": "f"
>         }
>     },
>     "g": "h"
> }
> ```